# Factorization of a fifth degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While doing self study I encountered the polynomial

$P = r^5 + 5r^4 + 12r^3 + 16r^2 + 12r + 4$

which my textbook factorizes, without provinding any intermediate steps, as

$P = (r^2 + 2r + 2)^2(r + 1)$

I tried to derive this result by myself but I got stuck due to my limited experience with factoring such large polynomials...
By using the Rational Root Theorem I was able to get the $(r + 1)$ factor and by using Polynomial Long Division I was able to rewrite $P$ as

$P = (r^4 + 4r^3 + 8r^2 + 8r + 4)(r + 1)$

How should I proceed now, from the solution I know I have to factor $r^4 + 4r^3 + 8r^2 + 8r + 4$ into a product of two quadratics but how do I arrive at the result that this product should be $(r^2 + 2r + 2)^2$?

Comment: There seems to be a mistake somewhere. $(r^2+2r+2)^2$ has a non-zero coefficient for $r^2$, but in your factorization of $P$ you don’t have that.

Comment: You could always try taking the derivative of $P$ and then use the euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of $P$ and $P'$.  If that gcd is not $1$ then its square divides $P$.  That should get you there, in this case.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I am not aware of this Euclidean method, is it common to solve such equations? If affirmative, could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Anna the most recent answer below uses this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the factorisation of $P(r)$ by $r+1$: you should find
$$P(r)=(x^4+4r^3+8r^2+8r+4)(r+1).$$
Now, to factor $Q(r)=r^4+4r^3+8r^2+8r+4$, a common trick consists in making a translation of the variable in order to simplify the polynomial and, hopefully, be able to factor the resulting  polynomial. Making the reverse translation yields a factorisation of the original polynomial.

Observe that, if we set $s=r+1$, we obtain
$$Q(r)=Q(s-1)=s^4+2s^2+1=(s^2+1)^2 =\bigl((r+1)^2+1\bigr)^2=(r^2+2r+2)^2.$$

Comment: nice trick, but how do you settle on $s=r+1$?  If you have to try many factors to find the right one, each involves a fourth power so that could be rather laborious.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: It's only a tool to try: you're never guaranteed it will work, as   there are irreducible polynomials with integer coefficients in every degree. You may program a computer algebra software to make the computations for more values than you could do by hand. It may also be used to prove a polynomial is irreducible using Eisenstein criterion after atranslation of the indeterminate.

Answer (score 3):

Every real polynomial can be represented as a product of real polynomials of degree 1 and 2.

Here you can write:
$$r^4+4r^3+8r^2+8r+4=(r^2+ar+b)(r^2+cr+d)$$ and multiply the right side and try to solve the system of equations for $a,b,c,d$.

(not hard to guess the solution)

Comment: I think it's easier in general to apply the euclidean algorithm to $P$ and $P'$ first.  But yes if you can just guess at the answer then that's always easiest.

Comment: @tong_nor I have the system $a + c = 4$, $a + b + d = 8$, $ad + bc = 8$, $bd = 4$. What's an easy/handy way to continue now in order to solve this system? I got stuck when trying.

Comment: the second equation should be $ac+b+d=8$.

Comment: Since you're looking for ANY solution of the system, first try in a particular set - the simpliest one, positive integers. Then $b=d=2$ or $b=1$, $d=4$ (or vice versa, but it doesn't matter). The first case leads to $ac=4$ and $a+c=4$, what gives $a=c=2$. It only remains to check that $a=b=c=d=2$ satisfy the last (unused) equation.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is looking for repeat factors, by finding the gcd of the original polynomial and its derivative.

The good stuff is:

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 12 x^{3}  + 16 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 4 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) }   $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 12 x^{3}  + 16 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 4 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 36 x^{2}  + 32 x  + 12 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 12 x^{3}  + 16 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 4 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 36 x^{2}  + 32 x  + 12 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 1 }{ 5 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{3}  + 12 x^{2}  + 16 x  + 8 }{ 5 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 36 x^{2}  + 32 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{3}  + 12 x^{2}  + 16 x  + 8 }{ 5 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 25 x  + 25 }{ 4 }  \right) } +  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 4 x^{3}  + 12 x^{2}  + 16 x  + 8 }{ 5 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x  + 4 }{ 5 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 1 }{ 5 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x  + 1 }{ 5 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 25 x  + 25 }{ 4 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 9 }{ 4 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 25 x  + 25 }{ 4 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 4 x  + 4 }{ 5 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right) }{ \left(  5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 6 \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 25 x  + 25 }{ 4 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 9 }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 12 x^{3}  + 16 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 4 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 36 x^{2}  + 32 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(  5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 5 x^{4}  + 12 x^{3}  + 16 x^{2}  + 12 x  + 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 25 x  + 25 }{ 4 }  \right)  -  \left(  5 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 36 x^{2}  + 32 x  + 12 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  + 10 x  + 9 }{ 4 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 2 \right)  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \left( 0 \right)  -  \left( 1  \right)  \left( 1  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 2 \right)  \left( 0 \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 2 \right)  \left( 1  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  - 2 x  - 2 \right)  $$

Comment: Yes that was exactly my suggestion, but you stepped up and did the heavy lifting so you deserve credit.

Comment: @GregoryGrant you can't go wrong with magenta